# asp.net webforms integration with paypal - testing failed credit card triggers is not consistent

Tags: asp.net, testing, paypal, payment

I am implementing paypal integration from my website - Calling Payment.Create PayPal REST API SDK for .NET, and PaymentExecution API to execute the payment. I am trying to test the integration in sandbox with invalid CC to avoid exploits and I have three difficulties:

1. how do I force a paypal screen that allows paying by CC (I mostly receive log or sign to paypal page)
2. When I insert rejection codes in the payer first and last name with a valid CC number some of the codes produce an error, but the API always returns 400 so I cannot distinguish between them.
3. Some of the codes are accepted without an error (for example CCREJECT-REFUSED, and CCREJECT-LS). and some are only rejected for American CC while not for other international ones.

for example testing simulated card 4032037158046959 with CCREJECT-SF triggers a payment.Execute failure with code 400 (no detail as the function did not complete), while the exact same transaction with same trigger and billing address and card 4580437386481810 succeeded. This varies considerably across CC and triggers and is never consistent. Also the initial page may be "pay with CC or log in" or "log in or sign in" and I cannot control that

Answer (score 0):

Use [the PayPal JS SDK for approval](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), which always renders a black "Debit or Credit Card" button when permitted for a transaction.

From the sounds of your question you've integrated with the old v1/payments API, which will still work but is deprecated. For new integrations only use the v2/checkout/orders API as documented in that link; the sample backend provided is in node.js but can be implemented in any language including asp.net. No SDK is used for these API calls.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. If I understand correctly the link specifies a template for the front-end while I cannot see a node-js backend. I am using ASP.net webforms as the backend. is there any reference where I can see a complete html/js front-end and asp.net webforms backend solution which I can integrate to my website? What did you mean by No SDK is used for these API calls? thanks you again.

Comment: corrected link. There is no (supported) SDK for the v2/checkout/orders API, the interface is HTTPS

Comment: Thank you! have converted node.js code to asp.net and manage to initiate transaction, but get the following - Could not initiate PayPal Checkout...
Error: "{\"id\":\"<id>\",\"status\":\"CREATED\",\"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://.../v2/checkout/orders/<id>\",\"rel\":\"self\",\"method\":\"GET\"},{\"href\":\"https://.../checkoutnow?token=<id>\",\"rel\":\"approve\",\"method\":\"GET\"},{\"href\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<id>\",\"rel\":\"update\",\"method\":\"PATCH\"},{\"href\":\"https://.../v2/checkout/orders/<id>/capture\",\"rel\":\"capture\",\"method\":\"POST\"}]}"

Comment: Is your backend responding with a 200 status code? Debug it in the browser dev tools Network tab before clicking a button. For anything further update your question with the JS code calling the backend and show the relevant Network tab activity when a button is clicked